# Custom uitextview class is nil in a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I've been learning Objective-C by myself for a couple of months and I am currently stuck on this task for quite some time.

I am using storyboard for this project. I have a custom `UITextView` (`PlaceholderTextView`) implemented in a custom `UITableViewCell` (`EditableTableViewCell`) which is in `WriteViewController`.

This is my code in `WriteViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EditableTableViewCell.h"
#import "PlaceholderTextView.h"


@interface WriteViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate>

- (IBAction)post:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *postButton;

@end
```

This is my code in WriteViewController.m:

```
#import "WriteViewController.h"


@interface WriteViewController ()

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation WriteViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    EditableTableViewCell *post = [[EditableTableViewCell alloc] init];
    post.postField = [[PlaceholderTextView alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"after: %lu", (unsigned long)post.postField.text.length); 
    post.postField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    EditableTableViewCell *post = [[EditableTableViewCell alloc] init];
    post.postField = [[PlaceholderTextView alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"begin: %lu", (unsigned long)post.postField.text.length);
    if ([post.postField.text length] != 0) {
        [self.postButton setEnabled:YES];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"PublicCell";
    static NSString* CellIdentifier2 = @"PostCell";

    if(indexPath.row==0){

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    if(indexPath.row==1){

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        }        
        return cell;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }    
}

- (IBAction)post:(id)sender
{
    EditableTableViewCell *post = [[EditableTableViewCell alloc] init];
    post.postField = [[PlaceholderTextView alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Click: %@",post.postField.text);
}

@end
```

After compiling and running, I print a few NSLogs when interacting with the `UITextView` and the "Post" button to see where I am getting in my project. This is what I get after typing in the `UITextView` and clicking the "Post" button. It seems that `post.postField.text` is not being registered and keeps printing 0.

> ```
> 2014-05-02 16:47:27.906 PostGap [19024:60b] begin: 0 
> 2014-05-02 16:47:28.107 PostGap [19024:60b] begin: 0 
> 2014-05-02 16:47:28.173 PostGap [19024:60b] begin: 0 
> 2014-05-02 16:47:31.598 PostGap [19024:60b] Click: 
> 2014-05-02 16:47:33.786 PostGap [19024:60b] Click: 
> 2014-05-02 16:47:41.552 PostGap [19024:60b] Click:
> ```

Here is the EditableTableViewCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PlaceholderTextView.h"

@interface EditableTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PlaceholderTextView *postField;

@end
```

And here is the PlaceholderTextView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlaceholderTextView : UITextView

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *placeholderText;

@end
```

All I want to do is get the `NSLog` to print what I am typing in the `UITextView` after clicking the "Post" button. I am getting stumped by this big time. Maybe it is due to my lack of understanding and experience in Objective-C.

Comment: You alloc and init a new `EditableTableViewCell ` and `PlaceholderTextView ` at each time you want to print what there is inside the text field. You must get the one which is in your table view.

Comment: I think that your problem is because you are instantiating a new `PlaceholderTextView` when you do `alloc` and `init`. In my opinion, the way is that you have to connect you custom cell class to the storyborad and the outlets inside it. After get the value inside the cell class and set some properties to work from your `WriteViewController`.

Comment: If you want a statics cells, you can add your `EditableTableViewCell ` and your `PlaceholderTextView ` directly in your `UITableView` through the Storyboard. Otherwise you must do it in the delegate `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Because in your case you add native `UITableViewCell` in your `UITableView`.

Comment: @BoilingLime, I have assigned    EditableTableViewCell    to the custom cell that the    PlaceholderTextView    is located in the Storyboard. How can I access the exact same property of    postField    in    EditableTableViewCell.h    and call it in     WriteViewController.m    ? Am I doing it wrongly in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your cell like this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"PublicCell";
     static NSString* CellIdentifier2 = @"PostCell";


   if(indexPath.row==0){

        EditableTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[EditableTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
            cell.postField.delegate = self;
        }
        return cell;
```

And remove all the code in your viewDidLoad..

Also change this:

```
    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{

    NSLog(@"begin: %lu", (unsigned long)textView.text.length);
    if ([textView.text length] != 0) {
        [self.postButton setEnabled:YES];
    }

}
```

I haven´t test this but i think this should work,
Good luck,

Comment: Thanks! You are one heck of a genius! I have another question though. How do I call `cell.postField` in `- (IBAction)post:(id)sender`?

Comment: @user3595616 can you tell me more about what exactly do you want to do in that method?

Comment: I want the `- (IBAction)post:(id)sender` to print an NSLog of `UITextView` which is linked to the `IBOutlet` `postField` after I've typed in it. I hope this helps.

Comment: @user3595616 and this post method is called by a button in each cell ? or there is just one button in the view controller?....if i have 10 cells and i write in 5 text fields when i press post should it print the 5 text in these textfields ?

Comment: there is just one button in the view controller where the post method is called by the button `postButton` in the second cell. There is only 2 cells in the view controller where only the second cell has a text field. The post method should print the text field after clicking the button.

Comment: IF always is the second cell, you can try this: NSLog(@"Text:%@",((EditableTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:1]).postField.text); @DaveJ

Comment: Thanks for helping out so far. I tried the code you posted but it gave an error: `implicit conversion of 'int' to 'nsindexpath *' is disallowed with arc`.
I replaced your code with this instead:
`NSIndexPath *indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"Text:%@",((EditableTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath]).postField.text);`
I don't think I am doing it right as I still get `Text:(null)` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

To print Log in - (IBAction)post:(id)sender

```
- (IBAction)post:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];
    EditableTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"postField = %@", cell.postField.text);
}
```